# magit search in buffer, only file names, not contents?

Tags: magit

If I run `M-x magit` I see a big list of staged and unstaged file paths. I want to search through the list of file names, using my usual Emacs command of `C-s` (`isearch-forward`). But in this magit buffer that also searches file contents -- not what I want. Is there a way to search just the file path list, and prevent it from expanding and going into the content of the files?

Comment: IIUC, it actually searches through the diffs, not the complete contents.

Comment: Magit supports `imenu`. In the Magit status buffer, press `M-g i` (or `M-x imenu RET`), then select the section you are interested in and you should be able to browse the files. The search is not performed using `isearch` thus this does not directly answer your question, but I hope it is a decent alternative.